# MSAL Azure Protected Web API giving error "Sign in to your account" in Postman and programtically in Android

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to access an azure protected web api which is working fine in browser but not working in Android app and in postman.
When I try to hit the Web API in browser, Microsoft authentication pops up and after success authentication, the response of the API gets pop up in the browser.
When I try to access the url in postman, I am getting "Sign into your account" html response .

I tried using Bearer Authentication token in postman but still getting html login response.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: An API should not be redirecting to the login page in the general case. You may have configured an interactive authentication method on the API instead of the Bearer token authentication method.

Comment: Thanks @juunas . I will integrate the Bearer token method and then respond in case issue still persist.

Comment: How do you change it from interactive to non-interactive? @juunas